# Whats wrong with the following java script it gives me Uncaught reference error for the function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate email address and zip-code, but this doesn't seem to work?
I am using `button onClick="validateForm()"`, should i use `input type="button"`? does it make a difference?

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("e1").value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var r1 = false;
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    } else {
        r1 = true;
    }
    var patt = /[0-9]/g;
    var zipc = document.getElementById("u1").value;
    var result = zipc.match(patt);
    if (result && r1) {
        alert("Pattern matches for both");
    } else {
        alert("Pattern doesnt match");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a great time to provide a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your code running with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me : https://jsfiddle.net/q4Lkkps4/

```
<input id="e1" type="text" />
<input id="u1" type="text" />
<button onclick="validateForm();">go</button>
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("e1").value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var r1 = false;
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    } else {
      r1 = true;
    }
    var patt = /[0-9]/g;
    var zipc = document.getElementById("u1").value;
    var result = zipc.match(patt);
    if (result && r1) {
      alert("Pattern matches for both");
    } else {
      alert("Pattern doesnt match");
    }
  }

</script>
```

Although same error as you said comes https://jsfiddle.net/dkyL41gr/

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
 function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("e1").value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var r1 = false;
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    } else {
      r1 = true;
    }
    var patt = /[0-9]/g;
    var zipc = document.getElementById("u1").value;
    var result = zipc.match(patt);
    if (result && r1) {
      alert("Pattern matches for both");
    } else {
      alert("Pattern doesnt match");
    }
  }
}//]]> 

</script>
<body>
  <input id="e1" type="text">
<input id="u1" type="text">
<button onclick="validateForm();">go</button>
</body>
```

Maybe you re using the script tags in a wrong way.

Please paste you test code here.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. For some unknown reason, the code seemed to work fine after i just took your code and used it on my project, worked like magic. I dont know what I did wrong, I have come to believe it had something to do with the function name, changed it a little in your code, and done. Thanks again